# Program won't function (maxMinArray)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a problem when I try to execute big a number of inputs. The goal of this program is print out the lowest number and the highest number in the array. My goal is to input 300 numbers, but my terminal refuses to accept that high amount. However when I input 100 numbers, it works perfectly fine. Can someone explain what's wrong with this program when trying to work with larger amounts of inputs and any suggestions on what I could do in order for the program to run?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class maxMinArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input = 3;
    int[] highLow = new int[input];
    int highest = 0;
    int lowest = 100000;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("input data:");

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        highLow[i] = scan.nextInt();
        if (highLow[i] > highest) highest = highLow[i];
        if (highLow[i] < lowest) lowest = highLow[i];
    }
    System.out.println("answer:");
    System.out.println(highest + " " + lowest);

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have 2 arrays high and low ? They have the similar content.

Comment: sorry im still kind of new, i fixed it tho @crashxxl

Comment: What do you mean by *"but my terminal refuses to accept that high amount"*?  I did an automated run (using `java.awt.Robot`) and it seemed to work just fine

Comment: so i copy pasted 300 ints when it asked for the input data and as soon as i pasted it, my mac just started beeping and it wouldn't execute. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You put 300 ints onto a single line?

Comment: yea, they'd all be recognized as separate ints tho right? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Assuming they are sepeared by spaces, they should be...

Comment: yes they are @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

Start by adding `scan.nextLine()` after `low[i] = high[i] = scan.nextInt();`.  There is still a carriage return/new line feed in the `Scanner`'s buffer after `scan.nextInt()` which will cause it to error the next time it tries to read it...

> so i copy pasted 300 ints when it asked for the input data and as soon as i pasted it

This changes things, try something more like...

```
String text = scan.nextLine();
Scanner parse = new Scanner(text);
int i = 0;
while (parse.hasNextInt()) {
    highLow[i] = parse.nextInt();
    if (highLow[i] > highest) {
        highest = highLow[i];
    }
    if (highLow[i] < lowest) {
        lowest = highLow[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

**Updated**

A better solution might be to put all the numbers into a text file and read the text file instead...

```
try {
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
    int i = 0;
    while (parse.hasNextInt()) {
        highLow[i] = parse.nextInt();
        if (highLow[i] > highest) {
            highest = highLow[i];
        }
        if (highLow[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = highLow[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("answer:");
    System.out.println(highest + " " + lowest);
} catch (FileNotFoundException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could use `Scanner` to prompt the user for the name of the text file instead of hardcoding it

Comment: @user3827195 See update...but the terminal just might not be able to handle that much input...

Comment: you were right about terminal .-.

do you know why it can't handle a large input?

Comment: Probably because it's input buffer doesn't large enough for that much of input at once...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've tried copying 400 number integers from 0 to 10000 and I have not gotten error. If does not work then the input buffer of your console does not allow a lot of data.

```
        int[] list = new int[400];
        int highest = 0;
        int lowest = 100000;
        int num;
        int n=0;
        String inputConsole;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input data:");
        inputConsole=scan.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputConsole);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                num=list[n++]= input.nextInt();
                if (num  > highest) highest = num;
                if (num  < lowest) lowest = num;
            } else {
                input.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("answer:");
        System.out.println(highest + " " + lowest);
```